# Problems scraping in python with Xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm trying to scrape all the crimes committed on this [webpage](http://www.mylocalcrime.com/#01001).  Each page I'd like to scrape is of the format "http://www.mylocalcrime.com/#" + zipcode.  However, when I view source either via python or on chrome, I don't get any data that lists the arrests.  I get a generic web page with a picture of each type of crime and a label of that crime.  For example, the source would say (and you can see this by viewing source): li <...>Vandalism /li> but the vandalism isn't a crime it's just a generic vandalism symbol with the content of vandalism.

I have tried using a Beautiful Soup and my code is basically:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
import requests

csvloc = '.../.../filelocation.csv'

ziplist = [1001]
listofcrimes = []

#with open(csvloc,'r') as csvfile:
#    ziplist = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

for each in ziplist:
    zipcode = str(each).zfill(5)
    page = requests.get('http://www.mylocalcrime.com/#'+zipcode)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

This request returns the html file of a generic page.  There must be a way to do it because when I use my desktop scraper it scrapes the result and provides an Xpath: //tr[50]/td ([] goes from 0 to 50).  Don't really understand Xpath well but there are no tr's in the source file I read.  Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off JavaScript in browser and load page again - and you see empty page.

All data on page are added by JavaScript and AJAX.

`lxml` and `BS` doesn't execute JavaScript so you can't find this data.

You can use `Selenium` (or similar tools) to control browser which will load page and run JavaScript and then you can get HTML with all data.

Or use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to see what url was used by JavaScript to read this data and then you can use `requests` to read data from this url. JavaScript mostly read data in JSON format which is easier to search data.

---

**EDIT:** it use API http://api.spotcrime.com to get data.

It probably needs account on server http://spotcrime.com and own `private key` to get data.

Example link from http://www.mylocalcrime.com which gives data as JSON:

http://api.spotcrime.com/crimes.json?lat=0&lon=0&radius=0.04&key=privatekeyforspotcrimepublicusers-commercialuse-877.410.1607

---

```
import requests

url = 'http://api.spotcrime.com/crimes.json?lat=0&lon=0&radius=0.04&key=privatekeyforspotcrimepublicusers-commercialuse-877.410.1607'

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.json()

crimes = data['crimes']

for x in crimes:
    print(x['type'], x['date'])
```

Result:

```
Arrest 01/26/17 03:38 PM
Arrest 01/21/17 09:30 PM
Arrest 01/20/17 05:09 PM
Other 01/16/17 07:50 PM
Arrest 01/16/17 11:14 AM
Assault 01/15/17 07:59 AM
Arrest 01/12/17 02:27 PM
Assault 01/09/17 10:45 PM
Theft 01/09/17 12:33 PM
```